# How to remove the h1 tag for the particular page in page.php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to **remove the h1 tag for the particular page** because **my page.php file coded is displaying the title for all the pages** but want to remove h1 tag(title) for particular page.

**code for displaying the titles for all the page:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 */
get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<section id="subbanner">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

            </section>
             <section id="subcontent">
<section id="service">
            <aside class="frame">

                                    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                        <?php the_content();?>


            </aside>
            </section>
               <?php endwhile;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**so i customized to my requirement for removing the h1 tag for particular page using if else statement by finding the page_id of the particular page but this doesn't work properly.**

```
<?php function remove_heading_for_particular_page() {
                if ( is_page('page_id=1757') ) {?>
                           <?php the_content();?>
                        <?php }else{?>
                                    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                        <?php the_content();?>
                        <?php }?>
 <?php }?>
```

could anyone help me to find solution for removing the h1 tag for particular page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `is_page()` properly. You have to use it like `is_page( 1757 )` instead of `is_page('page_id=1757')`.

So your `if` condition will be as like :

```
<aside class="frame">
                       <?php if(!is_page( 1757 )) { ?>
                        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                       <?php }  ?>
                        <?php the_content();?>


  </aside>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

[is_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function takes page id directly instead of string.

```
<aside class="frame">                    

                   <?php  if ( is_page( 1757 ) ) { ?>

                             <?php the_content();?>

                   <?php } else{ ?>
                                <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                                <?php the_content();?>
                   <?php }?>

 </aside>
```

Hope this code will help you :)